# How to show service notifications on the desktop

Tags: 19.10, services, notification

I want to show `sshd.service` notifications on the desktop to know if someone is connected to my PC using ssh.

I could track changes by using terminal and running `journalctl -t sshd -f`, but it requires additional attention from me in case of opening terminal every time, running the command and tracking changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it in the next way:

- Check if I could see service logs in journalctl: `journalctl -t sshd -f`
- Create new service that will run my `journalctl` command and output it using notifications on the desktop: `sudo vim.tiny /etc/systemd/system/shownotes.service`

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Show notifications from service on the desktop
  After=sshd.service

  [Service]
  Type=simple
  ExecStart=/home/user/test/output.sh
  WorkingDirectory=/home/user/test
  StandardOutput=journal+console

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```
- Create script: `vim.tiny /home/user/test/output.sh`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  export DISPLAY=:0 && journalctl -t sshd -f > /dev/pts/0
  ```

  I use `echo $DISPLAY` to get display value. `/dev/pts/0` - notifications output device. `sshd` - service, which syslog's output I will direct to `DISPLAY=:0`.
- Start and enable new service:

  ```
  sudo systemctl start shownotes && sudo systemctl enable shownotes
  ```

The state of the new service in real time I could see by:

```
journalctl -u shownotes -f
```

Results:
[image: notifications image]

But after rebooting and entering into Gnome session, not Kubuntu/Plazma, it started showing notification on `/dev/pts/2`